# How do I Sum fields in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: reporting-services, sum, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

This seems like it should be the simplest, turnkey, out-of-the-freakin-box, first grade task ever. But alas, 'tis not so.

All I want to do is add all returned values from a currency field together in CRM and stick into a report. Is that too much to ask? But instead of having some simplistic method of doing this first brainless activity, I'm stuck.

How do I create a calculated field in a CRM report with the result of a simple sum of values from a single field in an entity? To state another way for clarity: If I have any entity available and all applicably filtered records from a DataSet come back with only a single currency field selected, how do I Sum() all those returned values and show in a report?

Comment: Are you using fetchXml or SQL for your report?

Comment: Ideally, it would be nice to be able to do it within the CRM query editor (View/Advanced Find). I'm attempting to do it from within the Business Intelligence Studio environment and then import the RDL into the CRM since there doesn't seem to be a way to do it from the CRM UI directly.

Comment: `FetchXml` allows for some crude aggregation functions, though none through the standard interface. You'll get the most bang for your buck using SQL for reporting.

Comment: I'm heading in the SSRS direction. However, IMO, this is a crucial/critical feature that's so basic at it's core, I don't know that it's forgivable for the developmental powers that be to leave it out of CRM.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to accomplish the sum of fields you want from within CRM's report wizard or view editor. As Peter started to point out, if you are using the CRM fetch data source you will surely notice how the currency field in oyur query ends up as 2 fields in your SSRS dataset: one with the fieldname and one with "Value" suffixed that contains the numerical value of the currency field. I'm sure you found this out.

Salesforce users can accomplish this on forms directly with "formula fields" but not entirely sure how salesforce does it for reporting.

I totally agree calculating fields in the views is a simple and powerful feature Dynamics CRM has a big gap on. This feature gap only has 51 votes on [microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/675226/improve-fetchxml-query-expressions-and-linq-support-more-sql-please) so check that out and give it an upvote.

Comment: "Feature Gap" is putting it lightly. Not allowing intuitive aggregation on a query or reporting tool builder is like an auto dealer leaving the steering wheel, engine, or wheels off the car when they attempt to sell them.  ;)

Also, it appears your link is broken. Please edit when you get a chance and I'll do the upvote.

Comment: The link goes through for me, but I am currnetly logged in to a liveid/connect account. I think it wants you to log in prior to clicking the link -- check if your windows liveid account is hooked up to a connect account too (its been a while since I set up a connect account, but I do remember it wasn't standard) you MIGHT need a partner ID (unfortunately).